# set one of two classes according to a boolean variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a to-do list that looks like this:

```
        tasks : [
        { description: "make dinner", ID: false },
        { description: "make webpage", ID: true },
        { description: "walk", ID: false },
        { description: "watch tv", ID: true },
        { description: "study", ID: false },
        { description: "sleep", ID: true },
    ]
```

and I would like to display the ones that are completed in green and the others in red. I'm learning vue.js but can't figure out how to do this. This is the html:

```js
var root = new Vue({
 el: "#root",
 data: {
  tasks : [
   { description: "make dinner", ID: false },
   { description: "make webpage", ID: true },
   { description: "walk", ID: false },
   { description: "watch tv", ID: true },
   { description: "study", ID: false },
   { description: "sleep", ID: true },
  ]
 }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {background-color: powderBlue}
  .completed {color:green;}
  .notCompleted {color:red;}
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

 <div id="root">
  
  <ul>
   
   <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task.description" :class="here i need help"></li>

  </ul>

 </div>
 <script src="./vue.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: @Taplar ok done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the class like so:

```html
:class="[
   {
      'completed': task.ID,
      'notCompleted': !task.ID
   }
]"
```

Or Alternatively:

```
:class="task.ID ? 'completed' : 'notCompleted'"
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. Note that the ternary expression should be inside brackets

Comment: No it shouldn't need brackets. I did notice my answer was missing an apostrophe though

Comment: you're right, I read in the vue.js documentation an example in which they used brackets, but it works without them anyways